# opencv findContours() crashes the program

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing, and I'm working on a real time tracking

But I am stuck with the `findCountours` function.

```
cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_RGBA2GRAY); //convert to gray image
Mask = pImg->clone();  //clone the source
Mask.convertTo(Mask,CV_8UC1); //convert to 8UC1
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( Mask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0)  );
contours.clear();  
hierarchy.clear();
```

and when I run the program it crashes, If I comment the `findCountours` function it will be fine.

I have checked some documents but there is no clue what happened.

Comment: you need to binarize the input to findContours by e.g. applying threshold or Sobel. also, please avoid using pointers to cv::Mat, you'll inevitably thrash the internal refcounts this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mask = pImg->clone();  //clone the source
Mask.convertTo(Mask,CV_8UC1); //convert to 8UC1
```

replace

```
pImg.convertTo(Mask, CV_8U, arg);
```

**arg** may be different for different types of the input image. 255 for float/double.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "**Canny edge detector or Threshold operator**" before finding contours.
Choose your operator based on the task you need to perform.

```
   `cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_RGBA2GRAY); //convert to gray image
    Mask = pImg->clone();  //clone the source
    Mask.convertTo(Mask,CV_8UC1); //convert to 8UC1
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    /*based on your need use any of these operator */
    threshold( input, output, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value,threshold_type );  
   Canny( input, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
    findContours( output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0)  );
    contours.clear();  
    hierarchy.clear();`
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both 2 functions but actually I have got heap error just from the findcontour statement.